# How to keep Firefox open when I logout from a Linux shell?

Tags: firefox

I have the necessity to keep a Firefox instance running even if I logout from the current shell session, would be great if I don't use VNC or other similar software.
I have tried with a `CTRL+Z` and `bg` but the istance will close when I logout.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox exits when it loses connection to the X11 server (Xorg). You *cannot* simply override this without using "VNC or other software" – you'll need *some* kind of headless X11 server, such as Xdummy (possibly managed using Xpra), or Xvfb, or Xvnc.

Alternatively, look into web "browsers" specifically designed for scripting and headless operation.